# How to inject additional data to a jQuery ajax call with eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I'm developing a generic autocomplete for picking values from the DB (think selection a ProductID from a list of product names)

Since some types needs extra params to filter and validate the list, I have a `data-params` field in the input to capture the data from the form (or fixed)

I'm trying to feed the ajax call using this syntax `data-params='{ProductType1: $("#ProductType1"), ProductType2: $("#ProductType2")}'` in the input but I got this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Using only 1 param works fine:
`data-params='{ProductType1: $("#ProductType1")}'`

[image]

### jsBin for you to try

http://jsbin.com/atamez/1/edit

### This is the html

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="ProductType1" name="ProductType1" value="123">
    <input type="text" id="ProductType2" name="ProductType2" value="456">
<p>
    <span class="superlist">
    <input type="hidden" id="ProductID" name="ProductID" value="0">
    <input type="text" id="Product" name="Product" value="" style="Width: 150px;" 
         class="superlistinput" 
         data-controller="Products" 
      data-params='{ProductType1: $("#ProductType1"), ProductType2: $("#ProductType2") }'>
  </span>
  </p> 
</form>
```

### Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $('.superlistinput').each(function (i, el) {
        dosuperlistinput(el);
    });
});

function dosuperlistinput(el) {
    el = $(el);
    el.autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '/' + el.data("controller") + '/Lista/?term=' + request.term,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: eval(el.data("params")),
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            el.prev().val(ui.item.ID);
            el.val(ui.item.Nombre);
            return false;
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            el.removeClass('superlistinvalid');
            if (!ui.item) {
                var valoractual = el.val();
                $.getJSON('/' + el.data("controller") + '/ListaValidar/' + valoractual,
                    eval(el.data("params")),
                    function (json) {
                        var valid = false;
                        if (json.length > 0) {
                            el.prev().val(json[0].ID);
                            el.val(json[0].Nombre);
                            valid = true;
                        }
                        if (!valid) {
                            // it didn't match anything
                            el.addClass('superlistinvalid');
                            el.prev().val("0");
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    })
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
          .data("item.autocomplete", item)
          .append('<a>' + item.Nombre + (item.ExtraInfo === null ? '' : '<div><i>' + item.ExtraInfo + '</i></div>') + '</a>')
          .appendTo(ul);
    };

    el.keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode != '13' && event.keyCode != '9') {
            el.prev().val(0).trigger('change');
        }
    });

    addbuttonautocomplete(el);

}

function addbuttonautocomplete(el) {
    el = $(el);
    $('<button type="button">&nbsp;</button>')
        .attr('tabIndex', -1)
        .attr('title', 'Mostrar todos los items')
        .insertAfter(el)
        .button({
            icons: {
                primary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s'
            },
            text: false
        })
        .removeClass('ui-corner-all')
        .addClass('ui-corner-right ui-button-icon autocompletebutton')
        .click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            // close if already visible
            if (el.autocomplete('widget').is(':visible')) {
                el.autocomplete('close');
                return;
            }

            el.autocomplete('search', '');
            el.focus();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about this all wrong, you shouldn't use code to represent dynamic data just use data. For instance store the `id` of the element you want to get the value from (also how you have it now you aren't even getting the value just a jQuery element) e.g.
`data-params='{"ProductType1": "#ProductType1", "ProductType2": "#ProductType2"}'`

Now you can retrieve the properties and set the values.

```
var data = {};
var params = el.data("params");
for (var prop in params){
    data[prop] = $(params[prop]).val();
}
...
    data:data,
...
```

Comment: Ok, I guess that I already knew that but didn't want to do the extra effort :) BTW, for your code to work, the JSON must be encoded like this: `data-params='{"ProductType1": "#ProductType1", "ProductType2": "#ProductType2"}'`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to how you would do JSON with `eval` (before the native `JSON` object came around), you need to add parentheses around the string you are trying to parse, like so:

```
data: eval("("+eval(el.data("params"))+")")
```

That being said, there has to be a better way to do what you are trying to do here. Maybe you could just put the ID of the element in the data attribute and do the calling stuff from the actual JavaScript?

Comment: Tried that, but didn't work. (Illegal invocation in jQuery)

I don't know other way to do it. Sometimes the param is fixed, but sometimes I have to get the value from other input in the form...I could send the entire form serialized, but I think it's an overkill